# JNDI lookup is slow on OSX

Tags: java, macos, ejb-3.0, jndi

Making a simple JNDI lookup between Unix and OSX produces a large delay in OSX

Example:

```
initialContext.lookup(REMOTE_JNDI_NAME);
```

On OSX seeing timings of (12.158685s) whereas on Unix seeing timings of (0.201252s)

The JNDI lookup is of an EJB3 remote object e.g. ejb/TestAdmin#ClassName on a weblogic server

Any thoughts on what might cause such a difference in lookup timings?

Comment: Any thoughts about providing some hints as to what you're looking up? RMI? LDAP? DNS? CosNaming? Filesystem?

Comment: @EJP thanks, updated the description ... hopefully that helps